# Finding which letter has maximal occurence

Tags: matlab

I tried Matlab and the net to find an answer but in vain so I need your help
I have used the code below to find number of occurrences of the letters in an array;

```
characterCell = {'a' 'b' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'd' 'c' 'c'};  %# Sample cell array 
matchCell = {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'};                  %# Letters to count      
[~,index] = ismember(characterCell,matchCell);  %# Find indices in matchCell 
counts = accumarray(index(:),1,[numel(matchCell) 1]);  %# Accumulate indices 
results = [matchCell(:) num2cell(counts)] `
```

> results =
>
> ```
> 'a'    [2] 
> 'b'    [3] 
> 'c'    [2] 
> 'd'    [1] 
> 'e'    [0]
> ```

Now I need to get which letter has the highest occurrence
How to know the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index is the second output of the function `max`.

So you should do:

```
[~,index]=max(counts)
mostCommonLetter=matchCell{index};
```

Comment: what is the first output of function max?

Comment: It's the value of the maximum.

Answer (score 3):

The [mode function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mode.html) tells you the most frequent value.

```
mostCommonLetter = mode(matchCell[:]);
```