# Adding penalty to cell generating letters

Tags: matlab

I have combined the folowing posts 
[how to count unique elements of a cell in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285217/how-to-count-unique-elements-of-a-cell-in-matlab)

[Finding which letter has maximal occurence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438101/finding-which-letter-has-maximal-occurence)

to be able to find max occurance with penalty.
i.e. cell = 'a' 'b' 'a' 'c' 'a' 'a' 'e'
     penalty= [5] [2] [4] [2] [5] [1] [0]

```
 letterWeight= [1*5] [1*2] .....

now letter count will be 'a'[5+4+5+1]
                         'b'[2]
                         'c'[2]
                         'e'[0]
now maxcount= as done in max occurance
```

i just need a hint maybe i am missing something you can ease things on me thanks

need to add something on the last line but how?

```
enter code here str= num2cell(Allquants{p});
                matchcell ={'a','b','c','d','e'};
                [~,index] =ismember(str,matchcell);
                count = accumarray(index(:),1,[numel(matchcell)  1]);
```

Now the code is:

```
      plaincount = accumarray(index(:),1,[numel(matchcell)  1]);
      count = accumarray(index(:),penalties{p}{r},[numel(matchcell)  1],@sum);
```

Maybe it should be outside the loop? yes {r} should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the penalties into the second argument of `accumarray`, since it is these values that will get summed up (note that penalty needs to be numeric, so you may have to call `cell2mat`):

```
count = accumarray(index(:),penalties,[numel(matchcell)  1],@sum);
```

Comment: this is Penalties for i=1: TotalnoOfGrids for j=1: noOfNodes penalty{j}=(round(digit_size/2))- (char(Allquants{i}(j))-char(mostCommonLetters {i})); end penalties{i}=penalty; end When I do cell2mat(Penalties{p}) it is doing error! thanks

Comment: i was trying this [~,index] =ismember(str,matchcell)* Penalties{p}; without changing count

Comment: ok done with: count = accumarray(index(:),penalties{p},[numel(matchcell)  1],@sum); thanks

Comment: Hi @Jonas plaincount = accumarray(index(:),1,[numel(matchcell) 1]); count = accumarray(index(:),penalties{p}{r},[numel(matchcell) 1],@sum); are giving same results value count should be 7.3 giving 8 as if not counting penalties why?